# Webconfig inbound rule to avoid showing js files

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have created below rules

```
 <rule name="block js files">
    <match url=".*\.(js)/*$"/>  
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/notfound/{R:1}" redirectType="notFound"/>
    </rule>
```

This will move the request for js files to some not found page. and this is working correctly.

But when its also blocking the requested js files from the application.

I think the js files requested from the application lies under outbound rules.

So I want to put my above rules in inbound section as I believe request from browser lies under inbound rules.

What should I update here?

Thanks

Comment: "I think the js files requested from the application lies under outbound rules." That's completely wrong. All incoming requests are processed by inbound rules. To whitelist your own application, usually you should add a condition to verify referrer.

Comment: Is it really? I have written rules under outbound section to overwrite the js calls from the application folder to cdn bucket. and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think you could whitelist your domain from **HTTP_REFERER**. So that either you access the js from external or access it directly, IIS will redirect the request. At the same time, IIS won't block request that referrered from your domain. Of course, you could enable CORS header.

Besides, "notFound" is not a vaild redirectType. Are you looking for "Found" instead of "notFound"?

```
 <rule name="block js files" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*\.(js)/*$" />  
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/notfound/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="mydomain.com" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
    </rule>
```